# Source containers constraints for assignment optimization in CVXPY

Tags: python, optimization, knapsack-problem, cvxpy

I am writing an assignment optimization (multiple knapsack) in CVXPY with multiple items from multiple source containers to multiple knapsacks. The items each have a value and there is another associated cost of assigning items from each container to each knapsack (ex. shipping cost from sources to destinations). Each item can only be assigned to one knapsack.

My question is if it's possible to write a few constraints such that

- items assigned to knapsacks are in multiples of 88
- each bundle of 88 items have to be from the same source container
  Ex. Multiple bundles can be assigned from different source containers and the capacities of the knapsacks are also multiples of 88

example code:

```
import cvxpy as cp
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

knapsack_df = pd.read_csv('knapsacks.csv')
item_df = pd.read_csv('items.csv')
assign_cost_data_df = pd.read_csv('assignment_costs.csv')


capacities = knapsack_df['capacities'] ##capacities of each knapsack

B = len(item_df) ##num_items
C = len(knapsack_df) ##num_knapsacks
tc = np.sum(knapsack_df['capacities']) ##total capacities across all the knapsacks

x = cp.variable(B,C, boolean=True)

obj_item = cp.sum(cp.multiply(item_df['value'], cp.sum(x, axis=1)))
obj_assign = cp.sum(cp.multiply(assign_cost_data_df.values, x)) ##assign_cost_data_df has shape (B,C) as well
obj_supply = cp.sum(x)

objective = cp.Minimize(obj_item + obj_assign - 100*obj_supply) ##heavily reward algorithm assigning items

constraints = []

constraints += [cp.sum(x, axis=1) <= np.ones(B)] ##each item can only be assigned once
constraints += [cp.sum(x, axis=0 <=capacities] ##cannot exceed capacity of knapsacks

## todo: constrain assignment to multiples of 88 from same container

problem = cp.Problem(objective,constraints)
problem.solve(solver='CBC')
```

If the constraints are not possible, is there a way to at least minimize the number of containers being used and heavily weight that in the cost function?

something like:

```
obj_container = 0
for i in range(x.shape[1]): 
    obj_container = len(set(cp.multiply(x[:,i], item_df['container'].values)))
objective = cp.Minimize(obj_item + obj_assign - 100*obj_supply + 8000*obj_container)
## container weighted more heavily than each individual item so the optimization would need to source multiple items from another container for it to be "worth".
```

Essentially, is there a way to find unique/distinct items in `cp.multiply(x[:,i], item_df['container'].values)?`

Comment: `items assigned to knapsacks are in multiples of 88` Why not multiply the value of that item by 88 and say that that's one "item?"

Comment: The amount of items in each container may be more than 88 and each item has its own value. I don't want to "pre-group" the items into stacks of 88 because then I am potentially locking the optimization out of finding the optimal solution